# Limits a connected app access to the Case object

Tags: connected-apps

How can I limit a Connected App access to the Case object without using a dedicated user with a limiting profile to authenticate the app?

Comment: I dont think you can do without profile control.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: CRUD access is controlled via Profile or Permission Set (PS) - and running user has the Profile and 0+ PS. Connected App authenticates as a given user.